# Body on a frictionless rotatating surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

When we put a body on a frictionless rotatating surface. This body will be at rest relative to the non-rotating frame and analysing the body from lab frame we say $F=0, a=0$ but from the rotating frame the body would appear to rotate in the opposite direction. How do we analyse this rotation motion from the frame attached to the rotating surface?

Answer (score 2):

> How do we analyse this rotation motion from the frame attached to the rotating surface ?

There are two alternative methods:

1. Use Newton's laws to derive the equation of motion in the non-rotating reference frame, then convert the position of the object at time $t$ to the rotating reference frame.
2. Work entirely in the rotating reference frame, but introduce [inertial or "fictitious" forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force). In this case, the balance of centrifugal force and Coriolis force produces an inward acceleration towards the axis of rotation, which explains why the object travels in a circle in the rotating reference frame.

Comment: Yes, from the rotating frame,, it is as if there is a gravitational force acting on the "rotating" body.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there was friction and the body on the rotating surface was not moving relative to the rotating surface.
In the inertial (lab) frame there is a force $\vec F = -mr\dot \theta^2\,\hat r$ acting on the body.
The body is now observed in a rotating frame, whose axis coincides with that of the axis of the rotating surface, and the body seen to be stationary even though there is a force $\vec F$ acting on the body.
To be able to use Newton's second law an extra (fictitious/pseudo/centrifugal) force, $+mr\dot \theta^2\,\hat r$, is added so that the net force on the body in the rotating frame is zero.

You have asked about the "opposite" example with the body stationary in the inertial frame.
What is observed in the rotating frame?
The body is rotating, in the opposite sense to that of the rotating surface, about the axis of rotation of the rotating surface with no force acting on it.
To be able to use Newton's second law an extra (fictitious/pseudo) force, $-mr\dot \theta^2\,\hat r$, is added so that the there is a net force on the body in the rotating frame which produces a centripetal acceleration.